# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, The Thread Exited has with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c#, threadpool, matrix-multiplication, queueuserworkitem

```
    #region Parallel_Loop
    static void MultiplyMatricesParallel(int[,] matA, int[,] matB, int[,] result)
    {
        int matACols = matA.GetLength(1);
        int matBCols = matB.GetLength(1);
        int matARows = matA.GetLength(0);
        int count = 0;
        // A basic matrix multiplication.
        // Parallelize the outer loop to partition the source array by rows.
        Parallel.For(0, matARows, i =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matBCols; j++)
            {
                int temp = 0;
                int numThreads = (commonFeatures.resultMatrix.GetLength(0)* commonFeatures.resultMatrix.GetLength(1));
                int toProcess = numThreads;
                var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    new WaitCallback(delegate (object state) {
        rowColCall(matACols, temp, matA, matB, i, j);
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0) resetEvent.Set();
    }), null);
                resetEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }); // Parallel.For
    }
    #endregion


    public static int rowCol(int matACols, int temp, int [,] matA, int [,] matB, int i, int j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < matACols; k++)
        {
            temp += matA[i, k] * matB[k, j];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static void rowColCall(int matACols, int temp, int[,] matA, int[,] matB, int i, int j) {

        int a = rowCol(matACols, temp, matA, matB, i, j);
        Console.WriteLine(i + "," + j + " = " + a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hi,

I'm new on threadpool usage and doing matrix multiplication on c# by using thread pool(ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.) on row*col multiplication.
When I execute my code with Matrices {1 2 3 4; 0 0 2 4} and {1 4, 1 5, 3 6, 4,7} it returns me as output:

0,0 = 28
1,0 = 22
The thread 0x179c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1fd4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

So it calculates first two threads and waits in infinite loop; I don't know why.

Comment: It is at the discretion of the thread pool manager to add and remove threads from the pool.  How the pool was used before this code ran matters.  If this is an "it is not working" question then you forgot to mention what did not work.

Comment: @HansPassant The code must write (0,0 = 28 1,0 = 22 0,1 = 60 1,1 = 40) to the console.

Comment: That would be a very unlikely outcome.  Parallel.For() decides how many threads it uses, that will only be 4 by chance.  It picked 2.  The `numthreads` variable just doesn't have anything to do with the actual number of threads that are being used, you only add 1 with QUWI.  Fixing it is dangerous, you never want to write an algorithm that starts a polynomial number of threads.  Stop using Parallel.For() to get ahead.  It is best to not write your own matrix multiplication code, many other details matter.  Visit mathdotnet.com for example.

Comment: @HansPassant I got your point, and i replaced my code with the other basic matrix multiplication code. But still when I use QUWI for row*col multiplication, it blows.